# How to delete by id in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

My following code is for delete a element in array by the id of element but it is not working someone help me

Main.js

```
app.delete('/delete/:id', function (req, res) {

    fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        delete data["user" + req.params.id];
        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile('users.json', JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
            if(err){return console.log(err);}
        });
    });
});


var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address
    var port = server.address().port
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

users.json

```
[
    {
        "name": "alpha",
        "password": "123",
        "id": 4
    },
    {
        "name": "beta",
        "password": "123",
        "id": 5
    }
]
```

How to delete any of the above element by its id using postman or rest client api

Comment: You're not using a dictionary (associative array), so you need to do a search for the item with the appropriate key, and *then* delete it. This is basic javascript, and have nothing to do with node.js

Comment: Hy can you edit my code to perform delete method

Comment: Try this `delete data[data.indexOf(data.filter(function(d){ return d.id == req.params.id; }))]`

Comment: Can you edit my code

Comment: `fs.readFile(__dirname + "/" + "users.json", 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        delete data[data.indexOf(data.filter(function(d){ return d.id == req.params.id; }))];
        console.log(data);
        fs.writeFile('users.json', JSON.stringify(data), function (err) {
            if(err){return console.log(err);}
        });
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter your array to only include objects that have ids that don't match your deleted id.

```
data = data.filter(x=>x.id!=req.params.id)
```

Comment: Where to place this dood

Comment: replace the line that starts with delete with this instead, and spend some time checking out [functions that modify arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp) because you'll be doing it a lot in JS!

Comment: Happy to help, make sure to mark this as the correct answer!

Comment: can you help me to do the put method for update array element i dont have any idea on put method but i need that dood